# Bochner Integral of Positive Operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

So we have two function spaces (real or complex) X and Y (think $L^p$) and we say that a linear operator $P : X \to Y$ is positive if $f \geq 0$ implies $P(f) \geq 0$. I'm curious when a general (bounded) operator $T : X \to Y$ is representable as some kind of Bochner integral of some positive operators, e.g. something like

\begin{equation}
T = \int k(s) P_s \mathrm{d} \mu(s)
\end{equation}

where $\mu$ is defined on some measure space, $k$ is some scalar function and $s \mapsto P_s$ is a positive operator valued function. This is obviously always possible when $X$ is a finite dimensional space (EDIT: not completely true, see comment), but I'm interested whether this result can be generalised.

Comment: Even in the finite dimensional case, this can fail: Let $X = \Bbb {R} $ and let  $Y$ be spanned by $ \{(-1,1)\to \Bbb {R}, x \mapsto x $. The only nonnegative function in $Y $ is zero. This easily implies that the only nonnegative linear operator $X \to Y $ is zero.

Comment: That's an interesting point, I only thought about the case when you include all the functions. I guess one should assume something like: every function in $X$ (and analogously in $Y$) can be represented as a sum of nonnegative functions from $X$, which is certainly true for $L^p$ spaces.